# Axiom of Choice in Mathematical Analysis

Tags: analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, axiom-of-choice

I'm an undergraduate student and I'm looking for a book, suitable for self-study, that "explains" the applications of the axiom of choice in mathematical analysis. I'm not familiar with the axiom of choice, so I'd prefer a beginner-level book. If anybody could help me with this, I'd be grateful. I really don't know where to look for something like this.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you're asking for, but if you'd like a general undergraduate-level book on set theory, you could have a look at *Introduction to Set Theory* by Jech and Hrbacek. It has a good deal of discussion of the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Horst Herrlich - The Axiom of Choice

  Definitely worth looking into. It's very light on set theoretic proofs, at least compared to "the competition".
- Eric S. Schechter - The Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations

  Written from a functional analytic point of view. It contains a very thorough investigation of choice-related topic, and of course a lot functional analysis.
- David Fremlin - Measure Theory

  A very dense book, whose last volume is about set theoretic measure theory, and includes a lot of analysis without the axiom of choice, and what we can do and not do without choice.

Regardless to all that, I suggest that you study analysis first, and set theory alongside of it. Just to get used to the language and methods. Then learning about choiceless mathematics becomes easier.

Comment: Thank you very much about the advice. At what point do you think a student should start learning about choice? In MSc ?

Comment: Later during your undergrad studies can also be fine. But since most mathematics today uses the axiom of choice, you should first develop "correct intuition", and only later learn how to "spot choice" and the semi-intuition for choiceless mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

The [*axiom of choice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) is a result of existence (whose statement is in terms of sets and functions) in many books of analysis is used only to prove another result of existence: [*Zorn's Lemma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn's_lemma) whose statement is in terms of sets and weak order. See for example [Analysis Now](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387967885) by Gert K. Pedersen.

The vast majority of books of functional analysis only enunciate *Zorn's lemma* without proving it from the *axiom of choice*. The books of mathematical analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ need to state, for their purposes, only weaker results than *Zorn's lemma*: *[supremum axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property)* and [Well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) (Or the best known equivalent of the principle of the well ordering: [Principle of Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)).

The only elementary book of Mathematical Analysis that I have in mind at the moment which indicates more than three results directly from the axiom of choice is the one already mentioned above.

But most of the functional analysis books, prove several interesting consequences of Zorn's lemma for example:

- $
  \mbox{Zorn's lemma}\implies \mbox{Hahn–Banach theorems} \implies \mbox{Separating Hyperplane theorems}\implies\ldots $ 
  $ \quad \ldots\implies \mbox{Banach–Alaoglu theorem}
  $
- $
  \mbox{Zorn's lemma}\implies \mbox{supremum axiom} \implies \mbox{Intermediate value theorem}\implies$ $\implies \mbox{Rolle's theorem}  \implies \mbox{Mean value theorem} \implies \mbox{Fundamental theorem of calculus}.
  $

In the context of non-linear functional analysis: $\mbox{Zorn's lemma}\implies$ [Ekeland variational principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekeland's_variational_principle).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm more familiar with Zorn's lemma,, I've already had a math logic course where I had to use it in some proofs